# Update devise user from multiple forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm working on a site where the sign-up process is multi-step.. so many little forms all update the user model (i'm using the devise gem for user authentication).

Should I post each of these steps to the same update action (overriding the RegistrationController update action)? Each form may require some logic before the update occurs, therefore the forms will require some way of figuring out what form it's currently processing (either a hidden field or trying to establish from what params exist)

..or should I be posting the forms to individual actions (which isn't very RESTful)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not override the `RegistrationsController` to add an update action. I would have a completely separate `UsersController` that defines an `update` action that takes the parameters for updating a user.

Inside Spree (the thing I work on) we've got [an `update` action on `CheckoutController`](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/d67f8826d8fa30d768bc25297fd67c5ae79264b0/core/app/controllers/spree/checkout_controller.rb#L15-37) that works similar to how you want your users update action to work. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I think I should handle my multi-step process more elegantly like your Spree example.

Comment: Though how should I go about adding step-specific logic to process the params hash?

Comment: I would just have an object that transitions through multiple states like we do with the `Order` class in Spree. The update action then just knows what params to update based on the current state.